# Rails has_many, build, inverse_of

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations, has-many

I have 2 models like such:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :user_services, :inverse_of => :user

    validates_length_of :user_services, :maximum => 3
end

class UserService < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user, :inverse_of => :user_services

    validates_associated :user
end
```

I would like to do something like:

```
user_service = user.user_services.build(...)
if user_service.save
...
```

but it throws a "stack level too deep" error. I assume because of the validates_associated combined with the inverse_of. Does anyone know why this happens?

Calling save directly on the user object rather than the user_service object seems to work but I am wondering if there is a way to achieve these in reverse.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because your validates have circular dependency.

```
validates_length_of :user_services
validates_associated :user
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_associated

**UPDATE**

You can remove circular dependency if you rewrite your code this way:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_services, :inverse_of => :user
  validates_length_of :user_services, :maximum => 3
end

class UserService < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :inverse_of => :user_services

  def user_services_amount
     return 0 if self.user.nil?
     self.user.user_services.length
  end

  validates :user_services_amount, :inclusion => { :in => 0..3 }
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, it seems to be somehow connected to this issue i found: https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/5454-use-validates_associated-with-reverse_of-cause-infinite-loop

Comment: Add solution to this circular problem

Comment: Good solution. But it looks like _Remoove magic number refactoring_ needed: you could move magic **3** out of all checks with `User.max_services_allowed` method.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up! Works well.

Comment: Probably related to those issues:
[7809](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7809),
[16640](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/16640)